# SSH через OpenVPN

Tags: linux, ssh, openvpn

Есть пк c Linux на борту **нужно наладить ssh**!

Провайдер даёт только "серые" ip для обхода этой проблемы решил воспользоваться OpenVPN (vpn брался [здесь](https://www.freeopenvpn.org/))

OpenVPN ставился из репозитория и поднимался так.. (sudo openvpn /путь до файла конфигурации .ovpn)

Далее попытка подключится по ssh (ssh TheDog@46.30.45.178:22) но нечего не происходит. 
Возможно ли что нужно как то специфично открыть 22 порт для OpenVPN

Конфиг SSH /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Comment: вместо приведения абсолютно ненужного в данном случае файла конфигурации лучше бы описали, какое отношение, по-вашему, имеет openvpn к ssh.

Comment: «Ничего не происходит», это что за симптом? А с флагом `-vvv` что видим?

Comment: Вроде описывал выше ..
OpenVPN нужен для получение белого статического ip для подключения по нему по ssh ибо мой провайдер выдает мне свой  внутренний ip("серый") провайдера .

Comment: OpenSSH_7.3p1 , OpenSSl 1.0.2j  26sep 2016
debug1: Reading configuratetion data data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2:resolving "46.30.45.178" port 22 
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: connecting to 46.30.45.178 [46.30.45.178] port 22
debug1: connect to address 46.30.45.178 port 22:
connection refused
ssh:connect to host  46.30.45.178 port 22 : Connection refused

Comment: Ну вот и ответ. Правильно я понимаю, что вы стучитесь на ip, который ваш сервер получил при подключении к VPN?

Comment: Да. (подключаюсь к OpenVPN через выданный мне  ip [46.30.45.178] ).
Видимо там всё куда глубже ?!

Comment: Кто куда по ssh подключается? Openvpn туннель между кем? Чьи все эти адреса?

Comment: Туннель между openvpn и ssh . Openvpn используется  для доступа из сети интернет т.к у меня серый ip

Comment: увы, то, что вы повторяете изложенное в вопросе, не делает его понятней.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно я понимаю, что **Openvpn сервер находится на машине с "серым" IP**?

Если у вас динамический IP выдаваемый провайдером, то лучшим решением будет взять себе бесплатное доменное имя 3го уровня (например через no-ip.com).

Если ваш провайдер выдает вам внутренний локальный адрес, вида 192.168.*.* или 10.*.*.* и у вас есть собственный IPV6, то подключайтесь через IPV6.

Если ваш провайдер выдает вам **ТОЛЬКО** внутренний локальный адрес, вида 192.168.*.* или 10.*.*.* то единственное что вы можете сделать - попросить провайдера открыть на вас 1 какой-то внешний порт (возможно платно) и пустить VPN трафик через этот порт.